# NHibernate - QueryOver Child rows as comma separated values

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, queryover

I have to write a query where for each vendor I have to read vendor's contact numbers from `VendorContact` but instead in rows, one row for each unique vendor and one columns for each phone number as comma separated string in main result. This can be done easily in plain **SQL** but I have to do it in `QueryOver`. I cannot declare variables in `QueryOver` **SQL**.

```
var vendorvar = Session.QueryOver<Vendor>(() => V)
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => v.ContactNumbers, () => VendorContact)
    .SelectList(list => lst
       .Select(() => v.Name)
       .Select(() => VendorContact.PhoneNumber))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<VendorModel>())
    .List<VendorModel>();
```

There could be more phone numbers for one vendor, so I need like

```
Vendor         Contacts
------         -----------------------------------------
V0001          905-2343444,416-4545454,647-8484834
V0002          905-2356219,416-4111111,647-8000004
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if that is really so easy that way:

> ...This can be done easily in plain **sql** but...

just use that SQL statement in the raw query. There is some DTO for results

```
public class MyDto
{
    public virtual string FirstAlias { get; set; } // set name and type you need
    public virtual string SecondAlias { get; set; }
}
```

And here we do query, transform and list:

```
// raw SQL query
var query = session
    .CreateSQLQuery("Select " +
                    " SomColumn AS FirstAlias, " +
                    " SomComputedColumn AS SecondAlias " +
                    " FROM mySchema.MyTable" +
                    " join, where, order by..... "
                   );

// here we set transformer (check the aliases)
query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyDto>());

// and there is nice C# result
var list = query.List<MyDto>();
```