# Join Unrelated tables in Fluent Nhibernate with QueryOver or CreateCriteria

Tags: c#, join, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have tables :

- **tableAnnual** - AnnualAmount, AnnualCurrency. creationDate, Id
- **tableMonthly** - MonthlyAmount, MonthlyCurrency, creationDate, Id
- **tableSharevalue** - CurrentSharevalue, creationDate, Id
- **tableMiscDetails** - clientType, clientName, MarketValueAmount, creationDate

I have now to do the following select with NHibernate and QueryOver:

```
Select tableAnnual.AnnualAmount, tableAnnual.AnnualCurrency, 
tableMonthly.MonthlyAmount, MonthlyAmount.MonthlyCurrency,
tableSharevalue.CurrentSharevalue, tableMiscDetails.clientType, tableMiscDetails.clientName, tableMiscDetails.MarketValueAmount
from tableAnnual
outer join tableMonthly on tableAnnual.creationDate  = tableMonthly.creationDate
outer join tableSharevalue on tableMonthly.creationDate = tableSharevalue.creationDate
outer join tableMiscDetails on tableSharevalue.creationDate = tableMiscDetails.creationDate
Where id = 123456
```

Can someone give me a sample, how I can do that? - My Problem is, that I have to join multiple Tables mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Solution with NHibernate in this case, is either to use HQL

#### [Joining two unrelated view-tables with nhibernate and ICriteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26335220/1679310)

[14.2. The from clause (small cite and snippet)](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-from)

> Multiple classes may appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter
from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

Or create raw SQL. There is some example how to:

[NHibernate - QueryOver Child rows as comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32730333/1679310)